# Find element in list in bind result?

Tags: haskell

Say I have the list `[("sd", 55), ("s", 2), ("fgff", 23), ("s", 999)]`. How can I find the first occurrence of `("s", v)` and bind `v` to the associated value? So for example `someFunc "s" mylist` would return `2`. Optimally I would be able to pattern match and do `("s", v) = ...`

I am aware that I just could create a recursive function that itself uses pattern matching but I am looking for a more concise way that utilizes the already-defined functions of Haskell, like those in the standard prelude:))

Comment: @CrisLuengo I didn't see the answer(has not refreshed the page I guess) and found the answer on my own, so wouldn't waste anybody's time :)

Comment: Fair enough. Sometimes bad coincidences happen. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you *know* that the entry exists in your list `l`. In that case you could use a list comprehension:

```
v = head[v | ("s", v) <- l]
```

Alternatively (and the way I'd prefer) there is [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) which basically interprets a list of pairs as a dictionary, with the first entry as the key and the second entry ad the corresponding value:

```
Just v = lookup "s" l
```

Note that the `lookup` return value is wrapped in a `Maybe` to handle the case that the value does not exist.